# SSL - ASP.NET - Passwords passed in plain text when checked with Fiddler

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https, fiddler

I want to implement SSL with ASP.NET. I have generated a self signed certificate using selfssl. After that, I have assigned https bindings on port 443 (also tried alternate port 8443). When I access the website with https and enter credentials, fiddler shows passwords being passed in plain text. Why is that?

I am doing everything as it is supposed to be done. What am I missing? I have been all over the search engines for this and have done all of it but still missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Fiddler's certificate (which you shouldn't do on your production machine for security reasons) then Fiddler has the ability to decrypt and show you your SSL traffic. If that's not the case, make sure you are submitting your form *also* to an HTTPS link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Form is automatically submitted to the https link I believe because it posts to the same URL that was accessed. I am using a self signed certificate on the server side which I generated using selfssl. Can that conflict?

Comment: I don't think it will create a conflict while testing. Do you get any certificate errors when Fiddler is watching your HTTPS connection to other sites?